# What's spectral "tilt"?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, sound, speech

I am looking at article [Speech-in-noise intelligibility improvement based on spectral shaping and dynamic range compression](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiU4MGW9MXPAhXDLcAKHcHNClQQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flistening-talker.org%2Fdownload.php%3Ffile%3D6290f74023f6dbd81d85e1dc3f51f0d1.pdf%26type%3Dpaper&usg=AFQjCNEUDXrmtXEAmACiEtL6_Q8zVZIbfQ&sig2=2gCflNeI2z7We8XFK32cuw). In paragraph 2.2 the article mentions "tilt" of the spectral envelope. The tilt is computed using cepstrum, as follows:

> $$\log T(\omega) = c_0 + 2c_1\cos(\omega)\tag{2}$$
>   where
>   $$c(m) = \frac{1}{N/2 + 1}\sum_{k=0}^{N/2}\log E(\omega_k)\cos(m\omega_k)\tag{3}$$

$E(\omega_k)$ is the estimated spectral envelope (if needed see details in the paper).

What does the Tilt represent?

Comment: Usually, the term *spectral tilt* is used to describe the overall slope of the power spectral density. In many cases for audio signals, for example, higher frequencies have less power than the low frequencies (1/f characteristic) leading to a spectral tilt. As I have not checked the article you mention, however, the definition therein may deviate from what I have described above.

Comment: @applesoup Please, add this as answer.